# How to run map function synchronously in build function to stateless widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to run map function in my build function to create a list of objects which have id's which are present in another list but it return empty list.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../../providers/favourite_provider.dart';
import '../../providers/wallpaper_provider.dart';
import '../../models/wallpaper.dart';

class FavouriteScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _selectedwallpaper = Provider.of<WallpaperProvider>(context).items;
    final _favids = Provider.of<FavouriteProvider>(context).favourites;

    var _favouritewallpapers = [];
    _favids.map((tx) {
      WallPaper res = _selectedwallpaper.firstWhere((t) => t.id == tx);
      _favouritewallpapers.add(res);
    });
    print(_favouritewallpapers);
    return Center(
      child: Text('THis is favourite screen'),
    );
  } 
}
```

The print statement returns empty list. How can I ensure that it shows correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you should use `forEach()` instead of `map()`. This is because the `map` function is *lazy* - it does not do anything until you process the result of the `map`, which your code does not do.

I made an example based on your code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final _selectedwallpaper = [ {"id": 1}, {"id": 2}];
  final _favids = [1];

  // INCORRECT
  var _favouritewallpapers = [];
  _favids.map((tx) {
    Object res = _selectedwallpaper.firstWhere((t) => t["id"] == tx);
    print("res=$res");
    _favouritewallpapers.add(res);
  });
  print(_favouritewallpapers);

  // CORRECT
  _favids.forEach((tx) {
    Object res = _selectedwallpaper.firstWhere((t) => t["id"] == tx);
    print("res=$res");
    _favouritewallpapers.add(res);
  });
  print(_favouritewallpapers);
  return Center(
    child: Text('THis is favourite screen'),
  );
}
```

The output is:

```
[]
res={id: 1}
[{id: 1}]
```

Your code could be improved further like this:

```
_favouritewallpapers = _selectedwallpaper.where((t) => _favids.contains(t["id"])).toList();
```

Comment: I actually tried `foreach` earlier but it does not work at that time most probably because I didn't do full restart.